# csv file data is not getting written properly into excel - Dell Boomi

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-excel, boomi

I have a CSV file with multiple values separated by comma. I am trying to write CSV file data into an excel. CSV file have data like below-

create,DUS, 1 BOTOL PLASTIK @ 28 TABLET SALUT SELAPUT,31/01/2026,123456

In CSV file DUS, 1 BOTOL PLASTIK @ 28 TABLET SALUT SELAPUT is a single word. When this value is getting written to excel, process is considering comma for this value also and disturbing other field values in excel. Its separating the word rather considering a single word. Below is the configuration I have kept on flat file(CSV) level--

Use Column Headers - checked
File Type - Comma Delimited
Text Qualifier - NA

I want in excel to have the exact value to be written in the particular column. It should not disturb other column values in excel. Could someone suggest what changes I have to make.

Comment: Absent using some escaping mechanism commas separate field values. If all lines follow that format then combine the two fields coming from the CSV into one field before putting it into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy-paste the data to excel and then select the column where you have copied the data, go to Data>Text to Columns and then select comma as the delimiter.

Comment: Hi Arigo, thnaks for your response. Actually there is a requirement for writing a process in Boomi where csv file data has to be written into excel. I am not getting right output in excel because of one of the field value in csv having comma. Field value I have mentioned in description of the question.